# Postgres slow nested loop anti join for large and continuously updated table

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I have two tables, ingestion_event and ingestion_dependency where one or more records from first table is present in second table.

The records from second table is deleted by application when rows from first table are processed.

Application polls with first table to get rows which are not present in second table as:

```
SELECT a.*, dependency_key FROM (
    SELECT e.*, dependency_key
    FROM ingestion_event e
        LEFT JOIN ingestion_dependency d ON
                e.object_key = d.object_key AND e.root_task_id = d.root_task_id
    WHERE d.object_key is null
    FOR NO KEY UPDATE of e SKIP LOCKED
) AS a 
where  a.status = 'QUEUED' 
limit 100
```

```
"Limit  (cost=0.55..579.30 rows=100 width=1560) (actual time=16199.602..71206.977 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Subquery Scan on a  (cost=0.55..1436371.23 rows=248188 width=1560) (actual time=16199.600..71206.897 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        ->  LockRows  (cost=0.55..1433889.35 rows=248188 width=1470) (actual time=16199.599..71206.771 rows=100 loops=1)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.55..1431407.47 rows=248188 width=1470) (actual time=315.396..70222.109 rows=7457 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on ingestion_event e  (cost=0.00..424604.81 rows=917896 width=1362) (actual time=0.007..23196.192 rows=154371 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: (status = 'QUEUED'::text)"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 206432"
"                    ->  Index Scan using ingestion_dependency_object_key_idx on ingestion_dependency d  (cost=0.55..1.12 rows=1 width=219) (actual time=0.298..0.298 rows=1 loops=154371)"
"                          Index Cond: (e.object_key = object_key)"
"                          Filter: (e.root_task_id = root_task_id)"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"Planning time: 2.355 ms"
"Execution time: 71207.097 ms"
```

I have following index on ingestion_event:

```
(root_task_id ASC NULLS LAST, object_key ASC NULLS LAST);
(status COLLATE ASC NULLS LAST);
(root_task_id ASC NULLS LAST)
```

I have following btree index on ingestion_dependency column:

(root_task_id ASC NULLS LAST, dependency_key ASC NULLS LAST)
   (root_task_id, object_key)
   (root_task_id, object_key)

My question is why nested loop anti join is so expensive?
My postgres version is 9.6

Comment: Did you try a NOT EXISTS condition instead? More often than not that's faster than the "left join + is null" approach

Comment: Well, I did try not exists. It generates similar plan. I think both non exists and left join with key is null, generates the query plan